# Merge 2 arrays with no duplicated keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays like below and want to merge them together and not duplicate keys into a new array.

$array1:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [a] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/s] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/p] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => 1
                        [e] => 1
                        [d] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/u] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => 1
                        [e_a] => 1
                        [d_a] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

$array2:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a/x] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [a] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/s] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/p] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => 1
                        [e] => 1
                        [d] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/u] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => 1
                        [e_a] => 1
                        [d_a] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
)


$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

$result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [a] => 1
                    )
            )

        [a/s] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )

        [a/p] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )

                        [e] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )

                        [d] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )

        [a/u] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )

                        [e_a] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )

                        [d_a] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )

        [a/x] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [a] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

How would I go about making it look like this?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [a] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/s] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [o] => 1

                    )

            )

        [a/p] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => 1
                        [e] => 1
                        [d] => 1
                    )

            )

        [a/u] => Array
            (
                [p] => Array
                    (
                        [w] => 1
                        [e_a] => 1
                        [d_a] => 1
                    )
            )

        [a/x] => Array
            (
                [p] => 1
            )
    )
)
```

Am I going about this the wrong way or is there some way to clean this up? Examples welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function array_merge_recursive_unique($array1, $array2) {
  if (empty($array1)) return $array2; //optimize the base case

  foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && is_array(@$array1[$key])) {
      $value = array_merge_recursive_unique($array1[$key], $value);
    }
    $array1[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $array1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried user custom examples/functions from the `array_merge` page?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

There seem to be quite a few examples that might fit your bill. One suggestion for keeping keys (no renumbering) is to use the `+` operator

`$result = $x1 + $x2` (where x's are arrays)