# php - Merge two arrays and replace them

Tags: php, arrays, strtr

I want to merge two arrays and replace the text with `strtr` function.

I was using this before

```
$text = "cat cow";
$array = array(
"cat" => "dog",
"cow" => "bull"
);
$output = strtr($text, $array);
```

this returned `dog bull`...

Now I have two arrays like this...

```
$a = array("cat", "dog");
$b = array("dog", "bull");
```

Both the arrays will have values to replace

Now, how do I combine them and replace? I tried `$array = $a + $b` and `array_combine`, but they didn't work...

Please Help...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137140/merge-2-arrays-with-no-duplicated-keys

Comment: `strtr()` returns a string so you would have two arrays.

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of what you want the "combined" array to look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP merge array(s) and delete double values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180090/php-merge-arrays-and-delete-double-values)

Comment: if `$a` contains *keys* and `$b` contains *values*, then `$c = array_combine($a, $b);` - `$c` will have *replace pairs* for `strtr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think two arrays must be

```
$a = array("cat", "cow");
$b = array("dog", "bull");
```

And you can use

```
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
$output = strtr($text, $c);
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how you have tried.

```
$text = "cat cow";
$array = array(
"cat" => "dog",
"cow" => "bull"
);

$text = "cat cow";

$array = array("cat" => "dog",
"cow" => "bull"
);
$output = strtr($array, $array);
echo $output;
//output -> dog bull


$a = array("cat", "cow");
$b = array("dog", "bull");
$c = array_combine($a,$b);
print_r($c);
$output1 = strtr($text, $c);
echo $output1;
//output -> dog bull
```

I thing the above code gives you what output you need.

I think you have used the wrong array
Check the $a and $b array
I hope i have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean merge them to get array('cat','dog','bull')? If so just do:

```
$array = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b));
```

Comment: Could someone explain why the -1?  The question is/was somewhat ambiguous and this could very well have been a correct answer.

Comment: Indeed I believe I misunderstood the question entirely. Rather than back out and delete this, I'll leave it here in case anyone accidentally reads this and it helps them. Either way, thanks for requesting an explanation @EricH.

Comment: No problem.  I went ahead and +1'd your answer as I found it useful.