# How to merge 2 arrays with numeric indices and have values replaced in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I've 2 arrays nested to 4 or 5 levels coming from an external source (so, I can't, and don't want to manually, change the structure if possible). I've simplified the problem below but keep in mind that the structures are out of my control so I need a somewhat generic solution.

```
$x = array (
  'one' => 
  array (
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 
    array (
      0 => 3,
    ),
  ),
);

$y = array (
  'one' => 
  array (
    'three' => 
    array (
      0 => 3,
    ),
    'four' => 4,
    'five' => 5,
  ),
  'six' => 6
);
```

I want to merge these and get:

```
array (
  'one' => 
  array (
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 
    array (
      0 => 3,
    ),
    'four' => 4,
    'five' => 5,
  ),
  'six' => 6
)
```

I've tried all of the following and none give me exactly the above:

```
var_dump($x+$y);
var_dump(array_merge($x,$y));
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($x,$y));

var_dump($y+$x);
var_dump(array_merge($y,$x));
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($y,$x));
```

So, I guess I need some custom code to do the merge. What would it be? Keeping it generic and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function array_merge_recursive_unique($array1, $array2) {
  if (empty($array1)) return $array2; //optimize the base case

  foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && is_array(@$array1[$key])) {
      $value = array_merge_recursive_unique($array1[$key], $value);
    }
    $array1[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $array1;
}
```

Please search before post. This is a duplicate of [merge-2-arrays-with-no-duplicated-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137140/merge-2-arrays-with-no-duplicated-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Use Zend\StdLib\ArrayUtils::merge(), this method is used for merging config arrays in ZF2 and do that you want.

See:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayUtils.php